# TableView Scroll-bars Color Change By Java Code In JavaFX

Tags: css, tableview, javafx-8

I have change my TableViews style in code by-

```
    tableView.setStyle("-fx-base : #333333; -fx-background-color : gray");
```

Now I need to change the color of scroll-bar, using same way. Just only for this I do not want to add external css file. How can the scroll-bars color be changed ***using java code***?

Comment: The supported way of doing this is with an external CSS file. Is there any specific reason you want to do it a different way?

Comment: Then I have to add external CSS file. There only reason is still I have not added any external CSS file in this project and do not want to only for this as I have mentioned above. But now it has been important to change the color.

Comment: Exactly. It is better to separate the style into another file. It avoids cluttering your layout code with style information.

Answer (score 0):

A scrollbar contains several internal / private nodes that can be styled by using  these style class (thumb, track, increment-button, decrement-button, increment-arrow, decrement-arrow).

for example, If you want to change the thumb's color, you can do this:

```
 Node thumb = tableView.lookup(".thumb");
 thumb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
```

Comment: It's getting `NullPointerException` on second line.

Comment: you need to do this after the window is displayed (`stage.show()`)

Comment: Not getting exception, but also not getting any desired result. I tried removing tableViews css styling too.